# console log return null

Tags: javascript, html

i tried to do a popup and when i do my js in my html it work perfectly, but when i tried to separe my js of my html, my js file doesn't work and i don't know why...
i don't know if the problem its how i adapt my js or how my js is linked
if someone can help, it's will be really nice !

Here's my code, if you need anything else ask me ! :

```js
    
    var modal = document.getElementById('popup2');

    var essai = document.getElementById('id02');
console.log(modal)

    essai.addEventListener("click", function () {

        modal.style.display = "block";

    })

    var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span2.onclick = function () {
        essai.style.display = "none";
    }
```

```css
.popup2{z-index: 3;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.82);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Nejma Hamadi</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/stylesGallery.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

</head>

<body id="page-top">


    <section id="portfolio2">

        
        <img src="img/img2.jpg" id="img1">

        <div id="id02" class="popup2">
            <div>
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:30%" id="img001">
                <img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:30%">
                <img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:30%">
            </div>
        </div>


    </section>










    

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.0.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom JavaScript for this theme -->
    <script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/popup.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/popup2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popupVideo.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: put the script tags inside the head to start with. if that doesn't work, wrap your code in a self executing function

Comment: what says the console precisely ?

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML, you are using `popup2` as a **class name**, not an id!
Therefore, you should replace `var modal = document.getElementById('popup2');` by

`var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('popup2')[0];`

Another thing: make sure this code runs **after the HTML has loaded**, otherwise it will return undefined. To do so, wrap your code inside:

```
document.onload = function() {
  var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('popup2')[0];
  //your code here
}
```

Comment: ok, i tried to put a window.onload and now my console is not null : i added this code

Comment: window.onload = function() {
    var modal = document.querySelector('.popup2');
    var essai = document.getElementById('id02');
    console.log(modal)

    essai.addEventListener("click", function () {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    })
    var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span2.onclick = function () {
        essai.style.display = "none";
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with Jquery

```
$("#popup").hide(); //hidden in start
$("#openPopup").on("click",function(){
  $("#popup").show();
});
$("#closePopup").on("click",function(){
  $("#popup").hide();
});
```

see [CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dadmand/pen/PLOEwL)